How are medal prizes distributed in team sports in the Olympics?
I read that France is awarding 80k€, source CNBC, per athlete that earn a gold medal at the Paris 2024 Olympics. Is that also true for sport teams? Do all the squad get the same amount? Even the substitutes?
For instance, will handball or football athletes, even the substitutes, all receive 80k€ if winning the gold medal?
